# Having trouble converting user input into a graphic bar

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code seems to work fine when inputting numbers 1-9 but anything above doesn't work, what could be the issue? Here is the code:

```
var varkString = prompt('Enter your VARK scores - [visual|aural|read|kinesthetic]','9|3|11|10');
var subStrings = varkString.split('|');
var visual = varkString[0];
var aural = varkString[1];
var read = varkString[2];
var kinesthetic = varkString[3];
var varkBar = 30*visual
document.writeln('<img src="bar_blue.png" width='+varkBar+' height="25"/>');{
}
```

Edit: Solved

Comment: anything above doesn't work what r u trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing  first character when you are getting visual, second on aural and third on read.
I belive that you want to use subStrings

```
var visual = subStrings[0];
var aural = subStrings[1];
var read = subStrings[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are `slpiting` the string `varkString` the array will `automatically constructed` and assigned to `subStrings`.so use it like this:

```
var subStrings = varkString.split('|');
var visual = subStrings[0];
var aural = subStrings[1];
var read = subStrings[2];
var kinesthetic = subStrings[3];
```